# How to set the non-standard permissions for apps in Win10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, uwp

The permission model for Win10 store apps is quite involved. There are a number of different permission that one can grant or deny via the Settings app. However, if one looks at the apps in the store, there are sometimes (especially for Microsoft's own apps) a lot more permissions listed that an app can have.

Just one example: The [Skype UWP app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/skype/9wzdncrfj364) has a permission whose description reads "Close themselves and their own windows, and delay the closing of their app". Maybe I want to deny Skype that privilege. If I say close, Skype should close.

Is there a way to

- see a *full* list of possible permissions apps can have and which apps actually have them as well as
- deny an app some of the non-standard permissions, i.e. those that do not occur in the settings app?

Comment: What do you consider to be "non-standard" permissions?  Please edit your question to include this vital information. If a permission does not appear in the Settings UWP application then it cannot be granted or revoked. As for the Skype application, I don't see that permission, listed on any page linked from the link you provided

Comment: I clarified the question: "non-standard permissions" are exactly those that do not occur in the Settings app. The example permission I gave is the very last one on the list "This app can". Be sure to click "More", because the list is quite long.

Comment: not clear about your issue. Some apps permissions is designed when they were released by develop company, we could use UAC to control priviledge about apps and user account

Comment: Of course the permissions are requested by the developers. That doesn't mean I have to grant them. There is of course some internal process somewhere in windows that manages all the permissions, not just the ones in the Settings app. I want to know how I can look at this process and ideally manage it.